# How to set the initial Extends of the Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I want to add the ArcGIS MapServer/WMS Layers on the leaflet. And I want the leaflet map initialized with a specified  extent view ,then the layers can displayed well in the map.
    I had seen the leaflet API. There is no option to set the initial Extends of the map.There is a option to set the center and zoom  to control the entend but i want to set with the Lat/Lont or coordinate.Is There any way to solve this? 
  Thanks!

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70512/leaflet-wms-layer-from-arcgis-server-extreme-noob-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map.fitBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-fitbounds) right after map initialization.

Comment: Thanks! It solve my problem to initial WMS extends. And I have a new proble: the ArcGIs MapService Layer use the projected coordinate system, and the map.fitBounds() `p.fitBounds([
    [40.712, -74.227],
    [40.774, -74.125]
]);` use the  LatLngBounds, is there function to use the projected coordinate like `{"ymin":5088614.704999998,"ymax":5173351.580600001,"xmin":-7868916.0711,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857},"xmax":-7784294.4957}` to initial the extends?

Comment: Research into proj4js.